# How would I save form fields offline if connection drops?

Tags: javascript, mysql, jsp, prototypejs

I have a backend where people may take some time filling out the form.  The form is written to a temporary table every 5 minutes to store the data.  The problem I have is that some peoples internet connections are not strong, so they drop at times without the person knowing and when they go to submit, the form can't because of loss of connection.  Every 5 minutes I was going to add if the ajax fails, then prompt the user, but I want to go further and possible allow them to store the data offline and then reconnect to submit it.

The problem is, how would I start storing the data to a file on their local machine?  As far as I know, client side scripting can't create files and we couldn't use ajax to call a remote file that saves to a local file.  I suppose I could prompt to save the file at the beginning locally, but the local machine still would need to support the language.  We are using JSP with MySQL.

Does anyone know of how I would accomplish saving data offline when a connection drops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing offline capabilities can become a tough exercise. Your question is too broad to provide a final answer, but you should have a look at HTML5 capabilities, an overview is available [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/offline). Using this feature requires your users to use a modern browser version. You have to think of synchronization/replication as well.

If the connection only drops for a limited amount of time, it may be enough to just use a rich-client and store the data in memory using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the work :

First way:

1. Use HTML5 localStorage/session storage, or something like Gear to
   save the data on the client side
2. Make an ajax loop to ping the connection, idealy the server should be configured to reply with a http code 100 (I presume)
3. Send the data when the connection is on

Second way:

Use HTML5 offline capability or a substitue (see [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) and  [polyfill](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills))